# USA visa In Singapore

Tags: visas, usa, singapore, pakistani-citizens

I am travelling to Singapore next week on a visit visa and I'm thinking of applying for a US visa. Is it possible to apply outside your home country?

I have a Pakistani passport.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**It's possible, but not recommended.**. From the FAQ of the US Embassy in Singapore, #5:

> *Q.5 If I am a third-country national living in the Singapore, can I apply for a nonimmigrant visa in the Singapore?* [sic]
>
> Applicants are generally advised to apply in their country of nationality or residence. Any person who is legally present in the Singapore may apply for a visa in the Singapore . However, applicants should decide where to apply based on more than just convenience or delay in getting an appointment in their home district. One thing to consider, for example, is in which consular district the applicant can demonstrate the strongest ties.

http://www.ustraveldocs.com/sg/sg-gen-faq.asp#qlistgen5